# Semi-Automatic Text Highlighting in Images?

Tags: image-processing, automation, ocr

Greetings Overflowers,

Given that:

- I have images of documents with text of mixed languages
- I need this text to be highlightable (word by word) by end users
- I have this text in plain digital format already
- I will help my program to figure out where words are
- I do not want my help to be tedious to me
- I will also manually fix small inaccuracies after my program

What is the best easy help I can provide for my program to be able to draw rectangles around selected words ? What algorithm would you use for this program ? I tried OCR stuff like OmniPage Pro but they do not provide this functionality.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a word bounding box and highlighted words in my application some years ago.  You said "I have this text in plain digital format".  One key component is to have coordinates of characters or words in order to map them to proper image areas.  Like in searchable PDF, when you select text it is internally mapped to the image layer, and opposite selection on the image selects matching text.  But even from PDF those coordinates cannot be exported I believe.  If no such coordinate informaiton exists currently in your text, easiest is probably to re-OCR images with a high quality engine that can produce coordinates as part of output.  If you were to use WiseTREND OCR Cloud 2.0, then XML output will produce all that detailed metadata.  If coordinates informaiton exists, then all major components are there and it is just work around efficient UI design.

Comment: You know that you should be disclosing your affiliations within your profile and within any answer that mentions your products, right?  Also, you do understand that people loathe spam, and will react negatively if it appears you are spamming, right?

Comment: Hi Will.  The above answer is over a year old, and it is the way how I would accomplish the task if I were to do what geeko asked for, even today.

Comment: DISCLOSURE: I used to participate in development of WiseTREND OCR Cloud 2.0, and I used it to develop applications with functionality similar to what geeko asked for.  To my knowledge there were no alternatives at the time.